# Django Forms - change the render multiple select widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

In my model I have a manytomany field

```
mentors = models.ManyToManyField(MentorArea, verbose_name='Areas', blank=True)
```

In my form I want to render this as:

1. drop down box with list of all
   MentorArea objects which has not
   been associated with the object.
2. Next to that an add button which
   will call a javascript function
   which will add it to  the object.
3. Then under that a ul list which has
   each selected MentorArea object with
   a x next to it which again calls a
   javascript function which will
   remove the MentorArea from the
   object.

I know that to change how an field element is rendered you create a custom widget and override the render function and I have done that to create the add button.

```
class AreaWidget(widgets.Select):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        jquery = u'''
        <input class="button def" type="button" value="Add" id="Add Area" />'''

        output = super(AreaWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs, choices)

        return output + mark_safe(jquery)
```

However I don't know how to list the currently selected ones underneath as a list.  Can anyone help me?  Also what is the best way to filter down the list so that it only shows MentorArea objects which have not been added? I currently have the field as

```
mentors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=MentorArea.objects.all(), widget = AreaWidget, required=False)
```

but this shows all mentors no matter if they have been added or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the functionality you described sounds a lot like what you can achieve with using the ModelAdmin' `filter_horizontal` and `filter_vertical` settings.
The widget they render lives in `django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple`. You should have a look at its code!